# Meteor Session gets reset in IE 9 after navigating to another page via iron-router

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor, internet-explorer-9, iron-router

I have two pages for example, pageA and pageB.

In pageA, I set an value in Session

```
var student = {
  studentNumber: 'ABCDEF'
}
Session.set('student', student);
var s = Session.get('student'); // returns an Object 
console.log(s);
Router.go('pageB'); // navigate to pageB
```

I can see the Session (student object) has been set correctly.

In the clicked event in pageB,

```
var student = Session.get('student');
if (typeof student === 'undefined') {
  console.log('student object is undefined');
  return;
}
```

For some reason, the Session has been reset in IE 9. This issue only happens in IE 9, not in IE 10/11, Chrome, Safari.

I notice in IE 9. Every time, the page (for example pageB) seems been reloaded when we use `Router.go('pageB');` to navigate to. Does it matter?

Thanks in advance.

Jake

Comment: @RacingTadpole, unfortunately, I didn't. It maybe an issue of iron-router.

Comment: @RacingTadpole BTW, I am using HTML5 `sessionStorage` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks - I also developed a workaround using `sessionStorage`. I think the problem is that IE9 doesn't have something called `pushState`. I'll write up a short answer with some details.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that IE8 and IE9 do not have [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), so Iron Router doesn't maintain variables when changing URL with these browsers.

There is a discussion of the issue and possible workarounds on github [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/14).

It seems that the most comprehensive solution is to add [HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) to your project; according to the link above, it should all just work (although I haven't tried this myself).

Alternatively, as you have found, you can use `sessionStorage` to save the information between refreshes in a single session.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this.